# Should I create a separate table for every derived type?

Tags: c#

We are having a debate and I am struggling to decide which side to come down on.  Basically we have an event type lets say like like this (simplified example).

```
public class Event
{
    public virtual int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateTimeOccurred { get; set; }
}
```

Many different events in our system can inherit from this so we could have:

```
public class UserUpdatedEvent : Event
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

So basically any event can inherit from the base event and then we can track what is happening in our system which we need to do as tasks occur off these events, etc.

My question is should we have a table in the DB for every event so we can enforce foreign keys in this example to the user using table per type with each sub type referencing the base Events table.  Or should we have a single table and a column, maybe linking to an enum saying what the event is and then another column containing the primary key to that object but we won't be able to enforce referential integrity (maybe with a trigger but not ideal and not full proof).

The pros for a single table are speed, no joins, simpler to build/maintain, etc.  The cons are no referential integrity, we are using EF and table per type does work very well, on the other hand we produce a lot of reports and these are direct SQL sprocs for speed and the joins will become pretty heavy.

How do people normally come down on a situation like this?

Many thanks for any insight into existing systems with similar problems and helping us settle this decision.

Answer (score 4):

A single table is a good approach when the subclasses don't have many attributes or associations with other classes.

Otherwise the table would be full of attributes that only make sense for some rows and you´ll need to add all kinds of constraints to check that they only contain values for rows of the appropriate "type".

As you are suggesting, this really is a tradeoff, and you should weigh the benefits and disadvantages of both solutions.

Another approach you didn't mention can be to use one table per type and not use a common table at all. This way you need to repeat the columns in the different tables.

- You can have referential integrity
- You don't need joins to retrieve the information for events (at the row-level).
- You don't need type discovery in the application since you know which table you are querying.

Of course this also has some disadvantages:

- Unique key of an event: since they live in different tables you can't use an autonumber. You could circumvent this problem by using a GUID as your unique key.
- Querying an event of which you don't know the type.
- Querying all events requires one query per table.

In the end there's no "best" solution over all, there's only a best solution for your case. You're the only that has all the data and the information needed to make that decision.

Answer (score 0):

I will have to dissapoint you, but there is no simple thumb rule telling you how to model object inheritance in a relational database. However the widely used solutions are well documented and it is easy to find good articles about them listing the pros and cons.
The commonly used terms for your proposed solutions are (searching will be more efficient using these) :

- Using one table: Single table inheritance
- Multiple tables: Class Table Inheritance

Other solutions you didn't mention in your question:

- Concrete Table Inheritance
- Using Semistructured Data

You have to consider all the pros and cons to decide which suits your particular case best.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a addtional XML column that will contain all the addtional data requirement for inherited classes. This might be option of you have lot of variations that you cannot handle using tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would split object propeties into two tables.

One table contains the "core" attributes common to all classes and defined in Event. A classic table with one column per property.

A second table contains all properties that are different from those common ones. They are stored in a table with the columns type, id, key, value. (type is optional but can help you optimize your queries)

See EAV (entity attribute value)